# Translation to plot line with hough transform when using polar coordinates

Tags: python, opencv

I have a bit of trouble understanding how lines are plotted after doing a Hough Transform using polar coordinates.

On the [OpenCV example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) they do it like this:

```
a = math.cos(theta)
b = math.sin(theta)
x0 = a * rho
y0 = b * rho
pt1 = (int(x0 + 1000*(-b)), int(y0 + 1000*(a)))
pt2 = (int(x0 - 1000*(-b)), int(y0 - 1000*(a)))
```

I understand that they are taking two points far apart on the same line, but I have trouble understanding the "projection"/ multiplication by the sin for the x point and the cos for the y point.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: `(cos(theta), sin(theta))` give you the Cartesian coordinates of points lying on a unit circle. Scaling both by `rho` will give you points on a circle with radius `rho`... Fixing that to specific `theta` gives you a single point -- in that first diagram of the tutorial you refer to, it's where the blue and red line intersect.

Comment: Now also recall the definition of slope (dy/dx) -- so `a` and `b` also give you the vertical and horizontal components of the scale. Also recall that if we have a line with slope `m`, the slope of a line perpendicular to is will be `-1/m`.

Comment: The equation of line is y=Mx+B (not be confused with an and b) where M is slope and B is y-intercept. So equation of line is y=(−cosθ/sinθ)x+(r/sinθ).  The slope of the line r = tanθ = sinθ/cosθ. The line is perpendicular to r. So its slope is -1/slope of r = −cosθ/sinθ.  The y intercept comes from the upper left triangle where B is where the line hits the y axis. So we have B as hypotenuse and r is opposite θ where θ is equivalent at top left vertex and r=b*sinθ or b=r/sinθ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitions of `r` and `theta` are as shown.

So, the blue line directional unit vector **V** is `( cos(theta), sin(theta) )`,
and one point on the line is given as `r * V` (In your description, this is `(x0,y0)` ).

Points on the line can be obtained by moving along the line from this point.
The along directional unit vector **U** (which is perpendicular to **V**) , is `( -sin(theta), cos(theta) )` or `( sin(theta), -cos(theta) )`.

So, points on the line is :

`r * V  +  k * U`

where, value of the scalar `k` is arbitrary amount of movement. (In your description, used `k` values are `1000` and `-1000`)

---

Therefore, short answer for

> the sin for the x point and the cos for the y

is, **U** : the unit directional vector along the line.